# On the usage of the reference/resource request tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are currently 42 questions with the [reference-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) tag$-$I've just added a few. (The relevance of such questions for the site was already [discussed here](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1441/18081).)

Some of them ask for proper references, i.e., scientific publications about a given topic, while others ask for more general *resources* such as books on broader topics.

Considering the low number of questions, I don't think we should split them across two tags, but then the "reference" of the tag label could be misleading and prevent it from being used. I suggest that we do something like Astronomy SE: they have a [resource request tag](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resource-request), with a wider definition:

> Questions asking "What is a good book about X?" or more generally, "What should I read to learn about X?", typically where there is not a single authoritative reference. Also requests for multimedia, like video lectures.

and [reference-request](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reference-request) is just a synonym of this tag. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I can be for that.  Having two separate tags seems perhaps a bit better option, as those numbers aren't trivial, and it helps organize things, keeping two separate ideas separate.

Though I doubt anyone watches that specific filter or anything!  So it's not like the tag change would have many tangible benefits.

And I can see the other side, that having two similar tags for two separate meanings may only wind up causing confusion and more work to properly sort them.  I wound up grouping cloud identification requests with rock requests (before we disallowed rock ID questions), as it seemed unhelpful to hyperstratify topics like that.

So I am content either way.  A user passionate about such a tag like yourself is likely the best judge on such a topic, so I say go for it if you believe it a good choice!